# Making a transparent button

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am working on a Winforms application and imported the Windows API Code Pack for the Microsoft .NET Framework. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;    

namespace Glass_Test2
{
...
}
```

But when I tried to add a button on it, it turned out like:

[image]

Can any body tell me how to make the button here transparent?

Comment: is this a new app? Unless you're maintaining some legacy application or have to target really old operating systems I'd recommend using WPF instead. One of WinForm's biggest problems is transparency. You're walking towards a world of hurt if you're going to make an application that relies a lot on transparency with WinForm. Obviously if you know WinForm really well and WPF not at all then its a more tricky decision to make but if you're reasonably new to or experienced in both, definitely go WPF for this kind of thing.

Comment: Agree with @quibblesome, winforms doesn't support that. Better go the (sane) WPF way. Also, why is your question tagged ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't switch to WPF, I would go with GDI+ and draw rectangles - which can respond to mouse events. Now you have control over transparency.

```
Public Class GDIButton
  Public Property Bounds As Rectangle
  Public Property Text As String
  Public Property BorderColor As Color
  Public Property FillColor As Color
End Class
```